# How to reset Step count in Tizen Native to zero programatically

Tags: c, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I have a Tizen Native Watch app where I'm able to get the step count.
I have a need to reset the step count to zero on demand when I click a button or close the app.
Can you guys please help me with this. Currently, the step count is 60,000 and going on and on.....

Comment: Well, this is a programming Q&A site for specific programming problems and not the watch helpdesk.What's your specific programming problem?

Comment: How to reset the watch step count. When I print the step count it starts with 10000 steps and keeps on incrementing. Say if I walked 5000 steps during the day the count increases to 15000.  The next day when I print the steps instead of having a fresh start with count ZERO it starts from 15000. My question is how do I programmatically force the step count to become ZERO in Tizen Native C

Comment: Please edit the question and include all info there.